# Enable Proguard with react-native-firebase

Tags: android, react-native, proguard, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to enable Proguard with `react-native-firebase` freshly installed on my android project.

However I have an error from Proguard that I can't get rid of.

> Warning: io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService:
>   can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context
>   getApplicationContext()' in program class
>   io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService

I've tried to add the following, but it didn't work:

```
-keep public class android.content.Context
```

and this:

```
-keep public class android.content.* { public *; }
-dontwarn android.content.*
```

Those are the other things I've added to my Proguard file, the rest is from react-native. It looks like this:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep public class com.google.firebase.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**

-keep public class me.leolin.shortcutbadger.* { public *; }
-dontwarn me.leolin.shortcutbadger.**
```

Any idea how I could get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here - react-native+dependencies+gradle+pro-guard = dream team.. every build a new surprise.

Helped me for now:

```
-keep class io.invertase.firebase.messaging.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.messaging.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add also google play service.

```
# Google Play Services
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
```